# Setting up Mercurial on a Debian Wheezy server not quite working

Tags: linux, debian, mercurial, debian-wheezy

I am using Debian Wheezy and I want to set up a Mercurial server.

**Here's what I did:**

**1.** So, I first created the following directories:

```
/var/www/hg
/var/www/hg/cgi-bin
/var/repo
/var/repo/hg
```

**2.** Inside `/var/www/hg/cgi-bin` folder are two files:

**2.1.** hgweb.config:

```
[web]
style = coal
allow_push = *
push_ssl = false
[paths]
/=/var/repo/hg/**
```

**2.2.** hgwebdir.wsgi:

```
config = "/var/www/hg/cgi-bin/hgweb.config"
import cgitb; cgitb.enable();
from mercurial import demandimport
from mercurial.hgweb import hgweb
application = hgweb(config)
```

**3.** Then I created an entry into the sites of the apache2 and restarted it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName hg.********.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/hg
    WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^(.*)$ /var/www/hg/cgi-bin/hgwebdir.wsgi\$1
</VirtualHost>
```

**4.** After that, I added a repository called "default" here: `/var/repo/hg/default`

**Question**

So according to this, I should have a.) The mercurial user interface because "hgweb" is called in the script and b.) I should be able to pull from TortoiseHg. But none of this works yet. Instead I get an **error 404** when I call the domain.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

This seems to be the line that makes the problem:

```
WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^(.*)$ /var/www/hg/cgi-bin/hgwebdir.wsgi\$1
```

Because when I remove the `\$1`, it kinda works. It doesn't really work but it doesn't display an error 404 anymore. So what can I use to express this regex correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after trying different URLs:

This line

```
WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^(.*)$ /var/www/hg/cgi-bin/hgwebdir.wsgi\$1
```

should be replaced by this line:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/hg/cgi-bin/hgwebdir.wsgi/
```

And everything works fine :)